# Joining two dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I try to merge two dataframes based on the zip codes. But I only have zip codes for one country, so I would like to be sure, the other rows with other countries receive NaNs in the merged columns.

df looks like this

```
client     age-group     category     city     zip     country
4       18-24           basic         atown    12345   fooland
5       18-24           basic         atown    12345   fooland
6       <18             basic         atown    12345   fooland
5       <18             premium       ctown    12345   belgium
2       <18             basic         atown    12345   fooland
7       <18             basic         atown    12345   fooland
```

the other like this:

```
zip     state     population     ...
11111    a        17800
11112    a        15045
12345    a        13215
12349    b        5401
```

Zip in the second df is unique

Is there a faster and easier way to merge them, than using a for loop with `df.iterrows()`?

Comment: add a `country` column to your zipcode dataframe, and then merge on both `zip` and `country` columns, so pandas will only match clients from that country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` with `how='left'` should work:

```
df1.merge(df1[df1['country']=='fooland'].merge(df2, on='zip', how='left'), on=df1.columns.to_list(), how='left')
```

where `df1` is the dataframe you want to be filled with `NaN`s.

Comment: This won't work if there's a row from another country with a zipcode matching one zipcode from the country he has zipcodes for. You should add a `country` column to the zipcode dataframe and merge on both `zip` and `country` columns. See in OP that zip 12345 exists for both "fooland" and "belgium".

Comment: @DanielR You're right, I just edited the code to take care of that.

Comment: Just `df1.merge(df2.assign(country='fooland'), on=['zip', 'country'], how='left')` works

Comment: You may also find the validate option useful as it can check for different expected merge types (e.g. one_to_one, one_to_many).